Effect of adiabatic compression of air with cooling water
In the context of a hypothetical method for CAES, I was comparing the following two scenarios:
Assume that in the first case air is compressed in an adiabatic process from ambient pressure to something like 70 bar, i.e. 1m³ will be compressed to 14l.  The air will get hot, and according to the adiabatic compression formula I would expect temperature to rise from 20⁰C (293.15⁰K) to 817.69⁰C (293.15 * 70**((1.4-1)/1.4) = 293.15 * 70⁰·²⁸⁵⁷ = 1090.84⁰K).  Now if we have a second part of the system containing 14l water also at initially 20⁰C, we can in a second step allow heat exchange between the hot air and the water (with everything still isolated against the outside world), so both air and water will end up having some intermediate temperature, which I calculated to be close to 36⁰C (based on the heat capacity of both the water and the compressed air, see [1] below for the details).  But the heat transfer from the air to the water is irreversible, so in this two phase process, some energy will inherently be lost.  If the process is run backwards, even more losses occur and only a fraction of the invested energy can be retrieved.  Based on what I read about CAES implementations in real life, I assume that a round-trip efficiency of 50% is to be expected.
Now assume a second variant, where the compression is instead done in a way that heat is transferred to the water during the compression using some close to perfect heat exchange mechanism, so that the temperature difference between air and water remains negligible at any point of time. In this case, less energy is required to reach the same end state (wrt. to volume), so in the end, the water and the compressed air will be less hot.  I would like to know a way to calculate the final temperature under these conditions.  It should be somewhere between 20⁰ and 36⁰, but will it be closer to the lower or the higher end of the spectrum?  What formula could be used to obtain a good estimate?
Also, I suspect that the second process is (more) reversible, i.e. a larger share of the energy needed for the compression can be retrieved when this process is run backwards.  Assuming perfect conditions, i.e. total heat exchange between air and water during compression and decompression and total isolation against the environment, can this method approach a 100% round-trip efficiency, or are there other major inherent losses that need to be taken into account?
Thanks a lot for your consideration. I am not a physicist, so please forgive me if my question is not phrased well or does not use the correct terminology and please let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong. And in case you were wondering: It is definitely not a homework problem.
[1] We have 1.2 kg of air and 14 kg of water, and ignoring potential dependency of heat capacity on changing conditions, I assumed 1000 J/kg/⁰K for air and 4184 J/kg/⁰K for water, so in the two phase process, I would assume to have in the end (1000 * 1.2 * 820 + 4184 * 14 * 20)/(1000 * 1.2 + 4184 * 14) = 36.06⁰C

Where did you get that heat capacity value for water?

I got it from https://www.e-education.psu.edu/earth103/node/1005, but I just noticed I misread the article, so my figures are wrong. I'll correct them ASAP. Thanks for the good question.

Meanwhile I have updated the estimates with (hopefully) better values of heat capacity that lead to ~36⁰C instead of the 43.3⁰C I had in the first version.

For the 2nd version, from the 1st law of thermodynamics, you have $$(m_aC_a+m_WC_W)dT=-\frac{m_aRT}{M_aV}dV$$where $M_a$ is the molecular weight of air and $C_a$ is the mass heat capacity at constant volume for air.  The solution to this equation is $$\frac{T}{T_0}=\left(\frac{V}{V_{0}}\right)^{-\frac{m_aR}{(m_aC_a+m_wC_w)M_a}}$$where the subscript 0 corresponds to the initial conditions of the air.
